# PHP - init parent varialbles (with constructor)

Tags: php

I am newbie with php! I have task to create class(**Request**) that have constructor which have one parameter ($_SERVER) and another class (**GetRequest**) who extends **Request**. My code is:

```
<?php

class Request{
    protected $server;

    public function __contruct($ser){
        $this->server = $ser;
    }

    public function getMethod(){
        return $this->server['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    public function getPath(){
        return $this->server["PHP_SELF"];
    }

    public function getURL(){
        return 'http://'.$this->server['HTTP_HOST'].$this->server['REQUEST_URI']; 
    }

    public function getUserAgent(){
        return $this->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }
}

class GetRequest extends Request{

    function __contruct($ser){
        parent::__construct($ser);
    }

    //Return query string params in JSON format
    function getData(){
        $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,=,&]+/", $this->server['QUERY_STRING']);
        $arr=array();
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($keywords);$i++) {
            $i++;
            if (!isset($keywords[$i])) {
                $keywords[$i] = null;
            }
            $arr[$keywords[$i]] = $keywords[$i];
        }
        $obj =(object)$arr;
        return json_encode($obj);
    }
}

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].'<br/>';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $getReq = new GetRequest($_SERVER);

    echo $getReq->getMethod().'<br/>';
    echo $getReq->getPath().'<br/>';
    echo $getReq->getURL().'<br/>';
    echo $getReq->getUserAgent().'<br/>';
    echo $getReq->getData().'<br/>';
}

?>
```

But the output with **http://localhost/HW1/Task3/61807_new.php?http://localhost/HW1/Task3/61807_new.php?a=1&b=2** is following:

> GET
>
> http://
>
> {"":null}

Expected output is:

> GET
>
> GET
>
> /HW1/Task3/61807_new.php
>
> http://localhost/HW1/Task3/61807_new.php?a=1&b=2
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
>
> {"a":"1","b":"2"}

I can't see where is problem! It looks like **$server** is not initialize but i don't now why!

Comment: You are missing an 's' a in `__contruct`, it should be `__construct `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below code. There was a typo in your code, it is __construct and not __contruct :)

```
<?php

class Request{
protected $server;

public function __construct($ser){
    $this->server = $ser;
}

public function getMethod(){
    return $this->server['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}

public function getPath(){
    return $this->server["PHP_SELF"];
}

public function getURL(){
    return 'http://'.$this->server['HTTP_HOST'].$this->server['REQUEST_URI']; 
}

public function getUserAgent(){
    return $this->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
}

class GetRequest extends Request{

function __construct($ser){
    parent::__construct($ser);
}

//Return query string params in JSON format
function getData(){
    $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,=,&]+/", $this->server['QUERY_STRING']);
    $arr=array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($keywords);$i++) {
        $i++;
        if (!isset($keywords[$i])) {
            $keywords[$i] = null;
        }
        $arr[$keywords[$i]] = $keywords[$i];
    }
    $obj =(object)$arr;
    return json_encode($obj);
}
}

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].'<br/>';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
$getReq = new GetRequest($_SERVER);

echo $getReq->getMethod().'<br/>';
echo $getReq->getPath().'<br/>';
echo $getReq->getURL().'<br/>';
echo $getReq->getUserAgent().'<br/>';
echo $getReq->getData().'<br/>';
}

?>
```